# How to improve performance of cell segmentation using watershed algorithm with opencv-python

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, image-segmentation, semantic-segmentation, watershed

I have tried to segment cells in H&E-stained histopathological images using Watershed algorithm of opencv-python.
The code I used is totally same as Docs opencv code in link below.

[Watershed Code Source](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d3/db4/tutorial_py_watershed.html)

[image: Result Image]

But as you see the result, the performance of segmentation is not that much good.
Some cells could not be detected.

I want to detect all of cells at a time in that image.

In the case of cell in biomedical, I think this is more sensitive than normal object segmentation.

In original code, I added and applied two Blur algorithms before using cv2.morphologyEx().

```
img = cv2.imread("Path_of_Image")
img_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

# Convert to Binary Image
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

kernel = np.ones((3, 3), np.uint8)
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, iterations=2)

sure_bg = cv2.dilate(opening, kernel, iterations=3)
dist_transform = cv2.distanceTransform(opening, cv2.DIST_L2, 5)

ret, sure_fg = cv2.threshold(dist_transform, 0.5*dist_transform.max(), 255, 0)

sure_fg = np.uint8(sure_fg)

unknown = cv2.subtract(sure_bg, sure_fg)

ret, markers = cv2.connectedComponents(sure_fg)

markers = markers + 1
markers[unknown == 255] = 0

markers = cv2.watershed(img_rgb, markers)
img_rgb[markers == -1] = [255, 0, 0]

images = [gray, thresh, sure_bg, dist_transform, sure_fg, unknown, markers, img_rgb]
titles = ['Gray','Binary','Sure BG','Distance','Sure FG','Unknow','Markers','Result']

plt.figure(figsize=(12, 12))
for i in range(len(images)):
    plt.subplot(2, 4, i + 1),
    plt.imshow(images[i], cmap='gray'),
    plt.title(titles[i]),
    plt.xticks([]),plt.yticks([])
#     plt.figure(figsize= (5, 5))

# plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

There was a litte bit improvement, but still need changes.

How can I deal with this problem? Do I have to more examine Marker value or something?

I wonder your thinking.

Thank you in advance.

[Add]
This is Original Image.
[Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRPek.png)

Comment: Post your image. This forum wants reproducible code and example. Why did it not work or help?

Comment: The image I uploaded was not properly attached. I fixed it now

Comment: I'd recommend AI for this. semantic/instance segmentation. low level image processing, for such varied appearances, is at least a decade out of date. if you wanna stick with low level stuff, work with color information (staining). we'll need source data, not just a screenshot of a plot.

Comment: Please provide the original coloured input image with orignial resolution.

Comment: I added original image below! I processed by using this image.

Comment: It seems to me that you just need to adjust some thresholds for your application.

Comment: I must admit that I am struggeling to do the segmentation even manually. Can you give an example of how you as an expert would properly segment the image? Can you define rules, how the segmentation should be done?